# Remove text from middle of url

Tags: php, preg-match

Not the best way to do this...preg_match or rtrim.  Can't get either working...

```
$insert = http://www.site.com/buy/vancouver/house
$insert = rtrim("$insert", "/buy");
```

No change.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$insert = 'http://www.site.com/buy/vancouver/house';
$insert = str_replace('/buy','',$insert); // http://www.site.com/vancouver/house
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the first occurrence, you can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$insert = 'http://www.site.com/buy/vancouver/house/buy/dwed';
$insert = preg_replace('#/buy#', '', $insert, 1);
```